# What did Stravinsky mean: harpists "spend 90 percent of their lives tuning … and 10 percent playing out of tune”?

Tags: quotes

[*The Rough Guide to Classical Music* (2010 5 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848364768). p. 26 Top.

> #### Tuning & Temperament
>
> A central tenet of music-making is the desirability of singing or playing “in tune”, accurately producing sound waves that vibrate at the correct frequency. In practical terms, this means different things
> to different types of musician. Singers, violinists, trombonists and others who can slide smoothly
> between an infinite number of pitches rely on their ears and fingers to “tune” each as they go along;
> keyboard players simply call in a professional tuner every few months; while **harpists, according
> to Stravinsky, ”spend 90 percent of their lives tuning … and 10 percent playing out of tune.” [I bolded.]** For all
> this, tuning is today a highly standardized affair. An F sharp in Madrid is the same as an F sharp in
> Melbourne, and pianos in New York are tuned using the same system as those in Paris or Tokyo. But it
> wasn’t always so simple, as modern tuning relies on two basic principles, both of which took centuries
> to establish their global hegemony.

What's offbeat or outlandish about tuning harps, as Stravinsky insinuates?

Comment: I'd even question the 'facts' in the last two sentences. Standard A is NOT 440 Hz all over the world. Could it be a bit of a joke?

Comment: It's just a 'muso joke' - like adjusting one of the bass player's machine heads while he wasn't looking... then refusing to tell him which one.

Comment: It's a very old joke recycled. The original version was that a renaissance lute player spent more time tuning his instrument than looking after his horse.

Comment: The same joke is also recycled about hurdy-gurdy players, bagpipe players, viola players ... just about any instrument that requires tuning will probably have been the butt of the joke at some point. Stravinsky was just directing it at harp players in his iteration of the joke.

Comment: Did you consider that this would be anything else apart from gentle extracting of the Michael?

Comment: Welcome to the concept of a musical insult

Comment: @Greek - once again you are asking questions which are not on topic here. I'm going to migrate this to Music Fans, where it will be a bit more on topic.

Answer (score 2):

A violinist has four strings to tune.  A harp player has (typically) 47.  Stravinsky is jesting (with a degree of justification) that they don't even STAY in tune very long!

Comment: Harpsichordists have up to about 180 strings to tune, but J S Bach reputedly could retune an instrument in less than 15 minutes!

Comment: @alephzero I can tune it in 1 minute.  Oh, you want it tuned correctly?  :-)

Answer (score 2):

A concert harp is made out of wood with a mixture of natural gut and wire strings.  If you keep it in one place in a temperature-controlled environment, it can stay in tune for weeks.

But if you move it to somewhere that's warmer, colder, dryer or more humid, then it will quickly go out of tune.  So if you have a harp that gets dragged from concert hall to concert hall, it will need re-tuning before every performance.  And there are around 46 to 48 strings on a concert harp.

If you're unlucky enough to have a string snap, then the new one can take days or weeks to fully stretch.  During that time, it will constantly go flat.  For the first few hours, it will go flat as fast as you can re-tune it.